# error while fine-tuning Llama sequence classifier

Tags: nlp, llama

I am trying to finetune the model to my own dataset.
While I'm trying to train the code, it keeps getting this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmpPr.png)

should I just wait? Or is there a another way?
I'm running this on google colab, so I can't share my GPU.